# "internal compiler error" from yajl-ruby build on OpenSUSE 12.1

Tags: gcc, opensuse, chef-infra, yajl

As a requirement for chef-client, I am trying to install yajl-ruby on OpenSUSE 12.1. So far, it is returning the following message:

```
linux:~ # gem install yajl-ruby
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing yajl-ruby:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I.   -fPIC -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -g -g -fno-strict-aliasing  -fPIC  -Wall -funroll-loops  -c yajl.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I.   -fPIC -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -g -g -fno-strict-aliasing  -fPIC  -Wall -funroll-loops  -c yajl_alloc.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I.   -fPIC -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -g -g -fno-strict-aliasing  -fPIC  -Wall -funroll-loops  -c yajl_buf.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I.   -fPIC -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -g -g -fno-strict-aliasing  -fPIC  -Wall -funroll-loops  -c yajl_encode.c
yajl_encode.c: In function ‘hexToDigit’:
yajl_encode.c:201:1: internal compiler error: Aborted
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://bugs.opensuse.org/> for instructions.
make: *** [yajl_encode.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0/ext/yajl/gem_make.out
```

The appropriate packages are installed:

```
zypper install ruby ruby-devel ruby-ri ruby-rdoc ruby-shadow gcc gcc-c++ automake autoconf make curl dmidecode
```

It may be an issue with the compiler or there may be an issue specific on OpenSUSE. So far, I am not sure which path to take.

Comment: gcc clearly recommends you to send bug report to OpenSuse with full  preprocessed source (-E option instead of "-c" and add a redirect to file). This may be because opensuse gcc might have some modifications. You can check instructions on http://bugs.opensuse.org/ on next non-SOPA day. If the bug is in basic gcc too, opensuse bugzilla people will forward it upstream or will ask you to do this.

Comment: So I take it that chef doesn't work OpenSUSE yet? :)

Comment: No, this looks like "internal compiler error" for some rare configuration which can be fixed by using other compiler or even by changing `-O2` to `-O0`

Comment: That was it. Can you post that as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc clearly recommends you to send bug report to OpenSuse with full preprocessed source (-E option instead of "-c" and add a redirect to file). This may be because opensuse gcc might have some modifications. You should check instructions on bugs.opensuse.org and send a bug report to OpenSuse. If the bug is in basic gcc too, opensuse bugzilla people will forward it upstream or will ask you to do this

To avoid an "internal compiler error" without sending bugs you can try to change build options. Usually "internal compiler error" means that something goes wrong in complex process of optimizations, so you can just change this process (order of optimization stages and which are enabled). Easiest is to change level of optimization (e.g. replace `-O2` with `-O1` or `-O0`) or  add something like `-Osize`.